# Alcatel 4G modem seems to prevent access to HTTP sites

Tags: networking, http

I have an Asus laptop with Windows 10 x64 21h2.

When I’m home, I use an Alcatel MW40V 4G modem, via wifi, for connecting to Internet with a sim card by an Italian operator called TIM and when I’m in my office I use the wifi connection offered by my company. The Alcatel modem is updated with the latest firmware.

When I browse the web in my office I do not have any problem and I can connect to any kind of sites but when I’m home, using Alcatel 4G modem, I’m not able to connect to  HTTP sites (HTTP not HTTPS) since automatically the browser (any browser: Firefox, Chrome, Edge) is redirected to the webpage https://www.tim.it/timinternet.

Thinking it could be a security mechanism (since HTTP is an unsecure protocol) I thought that there must be some kind of internal firewall in the Alcatel that automatically avoid connecting to HTTP sites but, after hours of useless efforts, I was not able to find anything about it in the management web page of the modem.

My DNSs are 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

I also disabled Windows firewall and Avast antivirus, hoping that it could help but it doesn’t.

I What can I do for fixing this very annoying issue?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like your ISP might be trying to implement a captive portal.

I would try first removing those DNS settings and allowing your computer to obtain DNS automatically. Then, visit an HTTP page and, if you're still redirected to that webpage https://www.tim.it/timinternet, click on one of the buttons regarding your cookie preferences so you get to the next page with the message "Benvenuto su TIM, inizia a navigare!".

If it still doesn't work, next steps would be getting in touch with your ISP (TIM). You can also try providing a [snippet](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/#load) of the network activity caused by loading a HTTP page so someone can help investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround: I do not know why but the issue affected just my user account so creating another user account fixed the problem. It could be interesting to investigate why it happend.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with one of my clients.

Long story short, each time he tries to access a web application (issued by his organization) he gets redirected to https://www.tim.it/timinternet.

By accessing developers tools in chrome (F12) and going into the Network section, I saw that every attempt of accessing the resource got responded with a permanent redirect. Ticking "Disable Cache" in the network tab and clearing the browser caches solved the issue.
Hope that might help you with your situation, in my case only a specified website was being redirected.